# How to make a column in SQL case insensitive?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

The problem is the page linking process in wikimedia whereby I create a link [[like this]] or [[Like This]] creating two different links. A third and separate link would be [[LIKE this]] ... I was hoping to make the database case insensitive so they would all link to the same page. Here are some proposed solutions: I was attempting solution #6. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity_of_page_names

http://archive.is/Dm5YI#selection-376.1-393.32

Case insensitive means:

https://iglooo.000webhostapp.com/index.php?title=Computer_science

would return the same results as:

https://iglooo.000webhostapp.com/index.php?title=Computer_Science

Instead of a separate page like it currently does.

‘collate latin1_bin’ actually forces the mySQL column to be case sensitive.

Here is what I did, the key drop is required for the alter table:

```
alter table page drop key name_title;
alter table page modify column page_title varchar(255) NOT NULL default '';
```

There is table named 'page' that needs to become case insensitive. The above attempt at this has failed. Please help.

I am using the latest mediawiki distrobution.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Column names in SQL *are* case insensitive.

Comment: Collation only affects the sorting order. If  for example "Ab" and "aB" should be considered equal in WHERE use `upper()`

Comment: Why can't you standardise your data (lowercase/uppercase) before insertion or updating that column?

Comment: Provided links not working. What are the challenges/error you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried BINARY in your select query? Instead of altering your table, you can use something like: 
select * from table where binary col1 = ?;

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the alter table and the change of format for you column you can simply use a collate

in you query

```
col_name = 'Computer_science' COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

in this way the select column is used as case insesitive (by passing) you bin collation in table definition

Comment: This is my suggestion ..  if you want alter the table then alter assign a chaset with case insensitive .. (not _ latin1_general_bin  .. but latin1_general_ci  or  the default for mysql  latin1_swedish_ci;

Comment: A possible solution (directly related to MediaWiki) here: https://www.funkypenguin.co.nz/howto/make-mediawiki-page-names-case-insensitive-including-semantic-queries/

Answer (score -1):

If you don't clean the data going into the system, there is no way to store it in a case insensitive way. That being said, you can query on the data using a function.

```sql
select
    foo.bar
from
    foo
where
    upper(foo.bar) = upper(MY_PARAMETER)
```

Note, the right hand `upper()` cluase would be better handled in your application logic, but it's perfectly possible to do it here.